# How can I populate a textarea field with various field data from the web form?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

We've inherited a php/CodeIgniter app. Without going into all the reasons why, I need to feed values into a textarea field so I can group a bunch of data together and send it to a field in another app/outside vendor. This is the first time we have encountered this issue, but I don't think it is the last, so I want to prepare for it.

**The specifics:**

Web form with a bunch of fields on it.  It's a self generating php/CodeIgniter app that the client controls, so fields are different from client to client.

Certain clients may need to send data from 3, 5, 7, etc., of the field within their form to an external vendor who receives all the data in one field on their end. So in short, using jQuery, I want to send data from certain fields to a textarea field.

For example, I want to send Center Title, Full Name, and Fruits to the textarea field with a line break at the end of each. Of course, if the user empties a field, that line item would be removed from the textarea field.

**[Click here to view my jsFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/justmelat/HtKAL/)**

**HTML Example:**

```
<form method="post">
<br />
<br />
<fieldset name="Group1" style="border: thin; border-color: green">
    <legend>General Information</legend>
    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 249px">Center Title:</td>
            <td>
                <select name="centers" id="centers">
                    <option value="Corp 1">Corp 1</option>
                    <option value="Shamrock Gold">Shamrock Gold</option>
                    <option value="Hensin Way">Hensin Way</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 249px">Full Name:</td>
            <td>
                <input name="fullname" id="fullname" type="text" size="20" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 249px">Job Title:</td>
            <td>
                <input name="jobtitle" id="jobtitle" type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 249px">Known Alergies:</td>
            <td>
                <input name="knownAllergies" id="knownAllergies" type="checkbox" value="Yes" />Yes
                <input name="knownAllergies" id="knownAllergies" type="checkbox" value="No" />No
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 249px; height: 102px;">How Many?:</td>
            <td style="height: 102px">
                <select multiple="multiple" name="Select2">
                    <option value="one">one</option>
                    <option value="two">two</option>
                    <option value="three">three</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 249px">Fruits:</td>
            <td>
                <input name="Fruit[]" id="Fruit[]" type="radio" checked="checked" value="Apple" />Apple<br />
                <input name="Fruit[]" id="Fruit[]" type="radio" value="Orange" />Orange<br />
                <input name="Fruit[]" id="Fruit[]" type="radio" value="Fruit" />Fruit
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <label>Complete Info:</label>
    <textarea name="allVendorInfo" id="allVendorInfo" cols="50" rows="7"></textarea><br />
    <br />
</fieldset>
</form>
​
```

Comment: How does the user choose what fields to send to the `<textarea>`?

Comment: and How do you want text to be formatted in the `<textarea>`? JSON?

Answer (score 1):

You can access selections/user-input using following code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").change(function(e){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
        }else{                                  
        };
        var old = $('#allVendorInfo').val();
        $('#allVendorInfo').val(old+ "%" + $(this).attr('name') + '|'+$(this).val() + "%");

    });
    $("select").change(function(e){
        var old = $('#allVendorInfo').val();
        $('#allVendorInfo').val(old+ "%" + $(this).attr('name') + '|'+$(this).val() + "%"); 
    });     
});​
```

Comment: Greg - this will have to be a manual process on my part.  In and external js file for each client, I will add the jquery code noting the id's, names of their specific fields.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: Original fiddle was broken for some reason, have updated the link**

I was thinking something along the lines of this: http://jsfiddle.net/JRwzz/3/

The 'trigger' for this could be something other than the Run JS button of course, that's just there for example, i'd imagine it'd be on submit or other user action.

It clears the textarea first, then loops all of the input's and selects, depending on the type of element - checkbox, radio, select etc.. it uses slightly different methods to get the values (e.g. if it's a checkbox it only wants to get the value from a checked one)

It'll need a bit of polish in order to have a checkbox group's values all on one line and things like that, but hopefully this is enough for you to get the idea.

Then on each thing it finds it appends it to the textarea and puts a linebreak on the end.

It wouldn't be too hard to add a condition to check for another atribute (e.g. data-export="yes") to check for before including it in the textarea.

Just to note, I thought of it this way because you said all of the forms are dynamic, so I tried not to need to rely on ID's or names for things, it'll just apply to any form.  If you can get the code that generates your forms to output an attribute in the html on the ones you want included in your textarea (and perhaps some method of your client selecting which ones that'll apply to in their administration area) then that'd be spot on, would save having to fiddle JS for every client.

Comment: TreborBob - this is nice.  I am studying the code now, but question, is there a way to have the same effect on lost focus of each field, instead of having to hit the button to trigger the effect.

Comment: Yes you can bind the code to whatever events you can lay your hands on, e.g. $('#run').click(function() { ... }); could be $('form input, form select').blur(function() { .... });

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$("select, input").bind("change keyup", function() {
var form = $("<form>");
var data = new Object();

form.append($(":checked").clone());

$.each($("select"), function(i, item) {
    if ($(item).val() != null) {
        form.append(($(item).clone()));
    }
});

$.each($("input[type='text']"), function(i, item) {
    if ($(item).val().length > 0) form.append(($(item).clone()));
});

$("#allVendorInfo").val(form.serialize());

}).first().trigger("change");​
```